# Login with yahoo using OpenID for Multilingual site

Tags: javascript, asp.net, openid, socialauth

I am integrating yahoo open ID for my site. My site is running for different languages( en, jp, cn etc.). When I am trying to logged in from english site with yahoo opend ID then its fine but when the same this I tried from japanese or chinese site then it's not redirecting me to yahoo open id login.

Each time I am getting the below error from javascript

> Error: The character encoding of the plain text document was not
>   declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser
>   configurations if the document contains characters from outside the
>   US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be
>   declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order
>   mark as an encoding signature. Source File:
>   http://uatstorefrontjpcr.mobi-book.com/ReturnFromSocial/LogOnYahoo
>   Line: 0

Can anyone suggest what to do.

I have used SocialAuth-net.dll for this purpose. I have set all required wrapper in web.config. Same coding is okay with Google and facebook open ID.

Comment: I have found solution. So close this for now

Answer (score 0):

Your web server is probably sending back a response with a `Content-Type` of `text/plain`. When a web browser receives a response with that content type, it doesn't know what encoding should be used to decode it; since you haven't told it how to decode it, different browsers might choose different ways.

The solution is to provide an explicit encoding. For example, if you know that the text is UTF-8 encoded, then you could provide it in a header like so:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

According to [an informational page](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset#scripting) from the W3C, you can get ASP.Net to include that bit in the header using [`Response.ContentEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contentencoding.aspx). Again using UTF-8 as an example, you can set it like so:

```
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, But I have already solved this issue and closed